# Get all column from a database where column is not Null

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database, and I wanted to pull all the tables and their corresponding column names. I managed to do this using the following:

```
SELECT `TABLE_NAME`,  `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='Database';
```

But I wanted only column which are not Null for all rows, I tired the following but this did not work:

```
SELECT `TABLE_NAME`,  `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='Database' AND `COLUMN_NAME` IS NOT NULL;
```

But the result was identical to my previous query

Structure of the sample table from the database:

```
ID  Entity_ID  Balance  Security Purpose
A1  ADF1       32131    412      NULL
A2  JFJ4       51551    NULL     NULL
```

Comment: try this:  `AND COLUMN_NAME <> ''`

Comment: Sorry, didn't work , it says: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<>' at line 3

Comment: Can you add screenshot of your database table? so it will be easy to provide correct solution.

Comment: Sorry I understand the merit but the data is sensitive

Comment: Then do add sample data. Because if your "COLUMN_NAME" column does not have any record with value "null" or just empty then query will not work with `COLUMN_NAME` IS NOT NULL; or `COLUMN_NAME` <> '';

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT `TABLE_NAME`,  `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='Database' AND `IS_NULLABLE` = 'NO';
```

Comment: I think the OP wants only the tables that the columns doesn't have null values, not necessarily that the column is not nullable.

Comment: Does this remove a column if there is even a single Null, can you modify this to show if all rows are null

Comment: this will return all not null columns only

Comment: @GoudaElalfy: Your script yielded only only 2 column from a single table, I think the script is returning column which do not have even a single 'NULL', thanks for the attempt though

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will help.

```
SELECT `TABLE_NAME`,`COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='Database' AND `COLUMN_NAME`<>NULL;
```

Comment: This yielded an empty result, that is no rows were returned